# Remove xsi:nil attibute using IXMLDOMDOCUMENT in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2006, ixmldomdocument

I have an xml document that contains many xml nodes. The document has `xsi:nil="true"` attributes. If I set values on these nodes, the `nil` attribute remains and it becomes invalid against my xsd.

**Question:**

How do I remove the `xsi:nil` attributes using Delphi 2006 code with the MSXML2_TLB?

I tried this:

```
xmlNode.attributes.removeNamedItem('xsi:nil');
```

It runs without an error, but does not remove the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`IXmlDomElement.removeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759104.aspx) on the node itself, not the attribute collection. Any `IXmlDomNode` object that represents an element should implement `IXmlDomElement` as well, so type-cast the node:

```
OleCheck((xmlNode as IXmlDomElement).removeAttribute('xsi:nil'));
```

If you're using the *XmlIntf* unit instead of the Microsoft DOM, then call [`IXmlNode.SetAttributeNS`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLIntf.IXMLNode.SetAttributeNS). Pass [`Null`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.Null) as the value and the attribute will be removed:

```
xmlNode.SetAttributeNS('nil', 'xsi', Null);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more info in my question. I'm using Delphi 2006 and the MSXML2_TLB classes to access the Xml. The IXMLDOMNode class does not have a method for 'removeAttribute'. It only has one for 'removeChild' for which it throws an error when you supply the attribute as the IXMLDOMNode parameter. I'm afraid I have a tight deadline and so can't think about using a different technique to Micrsoft DOM at the moment. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The IXMLDOElement class has a removeAttribute method, but I'm struggling to populate element IXMLDOElement with the paticular xpaths I'm concerned with. Do you know how I get nodes (ones that are much deeper in the xml than the documentElement) into an IXMLDOElement object? Maybe I could attack it from that angle?